# Is it possible to have a tie in Munchkin?

Tags: munchkin

One of my friends asked me this question recently, and I couldn't answer it, so I thought I'd pass it along:

Is it possible to have a tie in Munchkin (elf assisting in a victory to have two people land on level 10 simultaneously)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes that is one way to achieve a tie. A [SJG representative](http://forums.sjgames.com/showpost.php?p=1327538&postcount=5) confirmed it (with a slight clarification with regard to being enthralled):

> Q: I was playing the original Munchkin game as an elf who gains a level for each monster that they help kill. I was enthralled to fight by a bard. We were both level 9 and killed the three monsters. Since we both gained the three levels we were both level 10 at the same time. Who wins?
>
> A: It's a Level gained by killing, so the Elf can, in fact, get the winning Level by helping.
>
> Missed the Bard wrinkle, so here's the proper official answer: The Elf couldn't have been enthralled in the first place. Had he been enthralled, before the win was on the line for the Bard, he still could have won the game, but if suddenly the Bard had the chance to win the game as well, the enthralled Elf leaves the combat outright. The Bard can still get help, but has to do it based on his real personality, not some Svengali like ability. . .

Comment: I was playing Munchkin with my sister and parents, and everyone was level 9 and i let my sister help me against a level 16 king tut and we tied and just... yeah...

Answer (score 9):

Another way to have a tie would be to have a Divine Intervention event grant a level to two or more 9th-level Clerics at once; Divine Intervention being a specific exception to the rule that you can only hit 10th level by killing.